# How to increase the 2nd number on a line

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

One thing I need to do frequently is to increment the *2nd* number on a line. Increasing the first is very comfortable by just pressing <kbd>Control-a</kbd>, but I just can't find a nice way to increase the 2nd.

There is no useful substring (as in, a word or a token or whatever) in that line that I can use for searches or jumps by text objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mean, it's basically a hack, but assuming you're at the start of the line with the number on it:

```
<C-A><C-X>w<C-A>
```

Go to the next number, increment it, decrement it, go to the start of the next word, increment the next number. This jumps past and increments the second number. Unfortunately it's not easy to chain as you need to repeat most of the keys again.

Comment: If you want to repeat it, you probably could record it as a macro.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the 'best' way, but 'a' way would be to create a mapping like this:

```
noremap <Leader>a ^/\d\+<CR>n<C-a>
```

- `^` to go to the start of the line
- `/\d+<CR>` to search for the first number
- `n` to go to the next (second) match
- `<C-a>` to increment the number under the cursor, which should be the second number now.

Or perhaps a slightly better way is to use a script

```
fun! IncSecond()
    normal ^
    call search('\d\+')
    call search('\d\+')
    execute "normal \<C-a>"
endfun
noremap <Leader>a :call IncSecond()<CR>
```

Calling `search()` doesn't set the `/` register and doesn't start highlighting if you have `hlsearch` set.
You could cram those lines in a keybind without a function:

```
noremap <Leader>a ^<Bar>:call search('\d\+')<Bar>:call search('\d\+')<Bar>:execute "normal \<C-a>"<CR>
```

But I would go for the readability of the function...

Comment: Thanks. I'd go with <kbd>Control-a</kbd> <kbd>Control-x</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>Control-a</kbd>, since I don't like to add nonstandard keybinds, but this would surely be they way to do it if I had to do it really often. Thanks!

Comment: @PhilippFrank Yeah, that's the better answer :-) Even if you wanted to make a keybind out of this, you're probably best off basing it on that ;-)